# in GWT, how to hide a part of the Text of CheckBox

Tags: gwt, checkbox

ok, let say I got:

```
CheckBox myCheckBox=new CheckBox("http://verylongurlverylonngurl_image.jpg");
```

I wanna hide the part `http://verylongurlverylonngurl_` of the text of checkbox, ie when seeing the check box on website it will show "image.jpg" as text of checkbox, but when we getText of that checkbox:

```
myCheckBox.getText();
```

it will return string "http://verylongurlverylonngurl_image.jpg"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you'd want `getText()` to be `image.jpg` and use [`getFormvalue()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#getFormValue%28%29) to get the *full value*: `getText()` is the displayed text, `getFormvalue()` is the *actual value* of the checkbox.

Comment: This is better way to do it, I also used to do like this.

Comment: the thing is I used getText for all checkboxes every where in my project, so if i use this then I have to change a lot & this feature is not too important , so i just need a quick fix. By using the above solution I just: CheckBox myCk=new ShortenCheckCheckBox("text",5);, & then I don't have to touch the rest of the code.
<br>  But this is good solution anyway, thax u for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own widget, if you only want to use it with `myCheckBox.getText();`

```
public class TextShortenedCheckBox extends CheckBox{
   private String original;
   public CheckBox(String label, int visibleLength){
        super(label.subString(visibleLength));
          original=label;

   }
   @Override
   public String getText(){
      return original;
   }
}
```

This is one way to go.

Comment: You awesome!, such a simple solution but very effective. Thax u vey much!